# LDAP user authentication access denied

Tags: ssh, authentication, openldap, ubuntu-14.04

Currently, I am configuring LDAP client for user authentication on the server.
Only SSH key authentication is allowed (Password authentication is not allowed).

My SSH configurtion (/etc/ssh/sshd_config)

```
PermitRootLogin no
AuthorizedKeysCommand /path/to/getsshkey.sh
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
PasswordAuthentication no
```

My other config files:

I have added following line in **/etc/pam.d/common-auth**

```
auth    required    pam_access.so
```

I have added the following line in **/etc/pam.d/sshd**

```
account required pam_access.so
```

I have added the following line in **/etc/security/access.conf**

```
-: ALL EXCEPT root (group1) (group2): ALL except LOCAL
```

I have also configured all these files (/etc/ldap.conf, /etc/nsswitch.conf, /etc/pam.d/common-session)

For an example ***username1*** belong to ***group1***

when I execute this command

> ssh -i private.pem username1@ip_address

I get below error in auth.log on the server

```
Access denied for user username1 by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Why is access denied?

Please help me

Comment: `ALL except LOCAL` denies all logins except local ones. SSH is not local login.

Comment: but when  add user instead of group name then it works   eg  -: ALL EXCEPT root username1: ALL except LOCAL

Answer (score 0):

personally I would use the `nss_base_<map>` directives as they are a bit more flexible and work with pam filters. however, since you are this far down the road, here is a good way to pinpoint your issue:

1st verify your LDAP information using the following commands

```
$ id
$ id YOURUSERNAME (will not show additional groups)

$ getent passwd
$ getent shadow
$ getent group
```

next check your pam filter configurations in `/etc/ldap.conf` and make sure the hostnames match

see the [LDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication) docs for more information.

Answer (score -1):

change the DNS NAME or set DNS NAME in customization.login the client machine change the Host-name   **hostnamectl set-hostname**.